# Block access to the apc.php file on nginx

Tags: nginx, apc

I need to disallow web access to apc.php file.

Tried a few ways,but its not working .

```
location = /apc.php { 
 allow xx.xxx.xx.xxx; 
 allow xxx.xxx.xx.xxx; 
 deny all; 
 }
```

Please guide me ..

Comment: How do you determine your IP address? Check what nginx get as you IP address (usually it's in access log)

Comment: Using below URL : http://www.myipaddress.com/show-my-ip-address/ identified the ipaddress .

Comment: And what nginx get as you IP address?

Answer (score 1):

use this nginx config to

**block all access to specific file `apc.php` located in your root folder**

```
location =/apc.php { 
    deny all; 
    return 404;
}
```

example:

- `http://example.com/apc.php` would be denied

or to allow only specific ip addresses to access the `apc.php`

**block all access to specific file `apc.php` located in your root folder, but allow access from ip XY**

```
location =/apc.php { 
    allow 192.168.178.1;
    deny all; 
}
```

Comment: I have added above configuration to the default configuration file on nginx server.specific ip addresses to access the apc.php is not working. It blocked and denied all the addresses

Comment: please remove the ``return 404`` and test it again

Comment: ok i have removed return 404 configuration while accessing the web url,But the apc.php file is downloading.

Comment: run into troubles again or now everything works fine?

Comment: Having the same problem, now the `*.php` file is downloading.